# No food allowed

Tags: ellipsis, headlinese

[image]

Can anyone explain grammar of sign “no food allowed”?
I got the meaning but confused about grammar. Why not “no food is allowed” ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-food-is-allowed.3095560/

Signs are often simplified and most are not grammatically correct. This one  sometimes gets a chuckle from native speakers, but we all know what it means.

[image]

Comment: You might want to explain why the sign is "funny", since it might not be obvious to English learners.  Also some references to explain this kind of "abbreviated English" might be good.

Comment: The sign means  "drive slow, because there are children who may run in front of your car"  But it is funny because it could mean "there are children here who are slow"

Comment: An interesting variation is the signs held by road crossing monitors [lollipop lady or man in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_guard) their signs read "Stop Children". The sign does not mean what is says, it is not promoting birth control, it means *"stop (please) and allow children to cross the road"*

Answer (score 0):

You are right. In signs and headlines, some words may be dropped.

As you have correctly guessed, *is* is dropped in this case.

However, it still works because you "got the meaning." That is the purpose of a sign -- to use the fewest words and still get across the meaning.

In this case, it is still grammatical. Sometimes signs may not be entirely grammatical.